# Website does not display on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new to Android dev and am trying to create a Web app. I want to check how the web page looks in my web app but it would not display (niether the localhost nor the web one) on the emulator. The webaddress (http://48.128...) worked on the phone when i got it connected it to wifi and checked it at my workplace. Any ideas ?

This is what i have tried so far ( http://www.vtgroup.com/index.html#LocalBrowser )

Comment: wow..! its also not displaying in my browser

Comment: @gtumca-MAC : argh. i hate when i am not able to understand if one is trying to help or making a mock. if you are tryin to help please come with some concrete details else have a nice day..

Comment: your URL is not working in my PC browser then how it will work in your android emulator ?... check your URL first

Comment: i should have generalize it. Replace my web address with yahoo.com or msn.com . That doesnt works either

Comment: have you given INTERNET permission? and check is internet works on your emmulator

Comment: ya, have given the internet permission and checked internet works on the emulator